# C# форма для подключения к БД через приложение

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Вопрос по C#.Есть строка подключения понятно что в Data Source=localhost прописываем ip или имя компьютера.....

"Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=testdb;"

Как сделать что бы можно было в приложении выбирать базу данных?
например нельзя же Data Source присвоить какой-нибудь переменной(мне кажется это глупость)

Comment: храните строки соединения в конфиге, оттуда их и считывайте, и с этими данными делайте выбиралку БД

Answer (score 1):

Используйте класс SqlConnectionStringBuilder, он позволяет безопасно построить строку соединения из данных, полученных на этапе выполнения (например, из TextBox):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
...

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = ServerName;
builder.InitialCatalog = DatabaseName;
builder.UserID = UserName;
builder.Password = Password;
string ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Если нужен продвинутый GUI для ввода параметров базы данных, можно воспользоваться ActiveX диалоговым окном OLE DB (оно строит строку соединения для провайдера OLE DB, а не обычного SQL Client, но суть та же):

```
//Добавить ссылки:
//COM -> Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library
//COM -> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library

string ConnString = "";
object _con = null;
MSDASC.DataLinks _link = new MSDASC.DataLinks();

_con = _link.PromptNew();
if (_con == null) ConnString = string.Empty;
else ConnString = ((ADODB.Connection)_con).ConnectionString;
```

Выглядит как-то так:

[image: Database selction dialog]

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2256149/8674428

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
public void StartConnection (serverName, dataBaseName, userName, secret){
    var connectionString =
        "Data Source=" + serverName + ";" +
        "Initial Catalog=" + databaseName + ";" +
        "User id=" + userName + ";" +
        "Password=" + secret + ";";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {     
        try{
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex){
            //обработали исключение
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно в роли `ServerName`, `DataBaseName`, `UserName` и `Secret` здесь могут выступать переменные, которые вы передаете в метод установки соединения.
[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631602/how-to-set-sql-server-connection-string)

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, как ваш ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: Все равно ни черта не понятно! У меня открывается приложение...Затем должно быть диалогове окно проверка подключения к БД...Т.е. как минимум 3 textboxа 1.Путь к БД 2.Логин 3. Пароль. Как мне путь к БД присвоить textbox?

Comment: Пожалуйста- в названии вопроса фигурирует "форма для подключения". И в теле высказано предположение о присвоении `Data Source` какого-то значения. В связи с этим я сделал предположение что ТС'у нужен настраиваемое соединение на момент выполнения запроса.

Comment: покажите пример кода? как это будит выгядить примерно?

Comment: @Миньон Я же в ответе привел пример метода, который открывает соединение которому вы передаете нужные параметры, разве это не то что вам нужно?

Comment: Да я понял уже...а знак @ не надо ставить перед "Data Source="? т.е. мы по сути прописываем  строку подключения в этом методе? Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: т.е. я могу в параметры метода передать значения из textbox?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Только учтите что у вас подключение закроется после выхода из метода, т.е. он направлен только на то чтобы протестировать открытие соединения.

Comment: Тестирование это хорошо...но основная задача что бы проверить и подключиться к базе данных...А так же что бы можно было к ней подключиться другим компьютерам. Как можно это сделать? не прописывать же это все в методе. Единственное если в конструкторе все это дело прописать?Или это грабли?

Comment: Вы сейчас вплотную подобрались к идее DBContext. С той лишь разницей что там настройки получают из web.config, а вы при первом запуске программы. Можно создать отдельный класс, у которого есть вышеуказанные поля, методы на соединение с бд и чтение/запись данных, и он имеет единственный экземпляр.

Comment: Да можно и config использовать, какая разница куда с формы сеттинги писать. Но ТС это не поможет, ему надо форму рисовать сначала :) а потом сеттинги сохранять/читать. А уже потом коннектиться к базе с помощью сеттингов.

Comment: И `SqlConnection` надо бы в `using` обернуть, и `try/catch` там использовать, с учётом что данные коннекта заполняемые это обязательно, как собственно и в другом случае.

Comment: Либо использовать глобальные переменные, но они есть зло.