# подключение к базам данных на c#

Tags: c#

Есть база данных к которой подключается приложение через форму. 
На Форме есть textbox куда необходимо вписать параметры подключения к базе так же должна быть возможность подключаться к другим аналогичным базам. Можно не через textbox подключаться,  я читал, что в ASP.net core можно менять конфигурацию в json файле. Есть ли такая же возможность в winforms? Важно что бы путь к БД не был жестко привязан в коде.

Comment: sqlconnection er

Comment: И в чем проблема? Кидаете на форму label, textbox и button. В лейбле пишете: "Введите строку соединения". Пользователь вводит ее в текстбокс, жмет на кнопку. В обработчике нажатия кнопки берете строку из текстбокса, создаете подключение (SqlConnection), вызываете метод Open... Далее показываете пользователю сообщение с результатом: успех или нет. | WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Дайте-ка угадаю. Вам хоцца показать пользователю список уже имеющихся серверов СУБД, чтобы он выбрал из них нужный (с помощью combobox), а не вводил строку вручную? Ну так наймите программиста. Или хотя бы того, кто сможет четко описать в вопросе, что именно нужно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# форма для подключения к БД через приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853725/c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Александр Петров я хочу сам научиться а не нанимать кого-либо. А тут спрашиваю потому что не нашел соответствующую литературу. Что в вопросе было не понятно? Можно combobox, можно textbox нужно что бы можно было из приложения подключаться с любого ПК. Например указав IP адрес машины где крутиться база данных.

Comment: Указывайте символ `@` перед ником того, к кому обращаетесь. | Повторяю вопрос еще раз: вы хотите сделать, чтобы пользователь сам вводил строку соединения (как я описал в первом комментарии) или показать ему готовый список с имеющимися подключениями? Повторяю второй вопрос: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Я хочу что бы пользователь прописывал путь к БД. Делаю все это на WinForms

Comment: То есть ваш вопрос теперь сводится к следующему: как прочитать строку подключения из файла.

Comment: Можете создать статический путь без textbox. Я разрабатывал десктопый приложение на winforms. Сам база находился у меня в проекте.

Comment: Стандартным способом является хранение строк соединения в файле конфигурации. [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)